# How to remove listview items?

Tags: document-library, list-view

I have got a listview. But I don't want anybody add new documents. I want to remove or close new upload share buttons. Is it possible?

Comment: Refer this similar question/answer - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219675/how-i-can-remove-the-edit-this-list-link-from-my-web-app-toolbar/219682#219682

Comment: You can check below link if using sharepoint 2013 later
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62978074/10403065

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer and may be this help for someone.

1. Click on Gear icon > Edit page from top right corner of your ribbon
2. Edit the web part's properties
3. For Toolbar Type, select "No Toolbar"
4. Click on OK
   Then , it will remove the edit buttons on thwe top of the listview.